# Background FCM messages work on emulator but not on device. Flutter - "Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'package:my_fcm.dart' not found."

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

From adb logcat, I see

```
 E flutter : [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(93)] Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'package:flutter_starter/starterlib/my_fcm.dart' not found.
```

where `my_fcm.dart` is the file containing my `firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler`, registered with `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler)`

`firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler` is a global variable (ie. declared outside any class).

The fact that it works in the emulator, but not on the device, makes me think it might be some kind of bundling error when creating the apk. Or have I simply misunderstood how to declare a background function?

Answer (score 3):

Just before posting, I found the answer, but I'm posting anyway to help others with the same problem.

The solution is described here https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/9446#issuecomment-1240554285

and is to add `@pragma('vm:entry-point')` to the background handler definition.